# Exit probability on a finite interval

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a question about the estimate of the exit probability on a finite interval. Given a $q$ function bounded and continuous, given the following SDE 
\begin{cases}
dX_s=(\beta-q(s))X_sds+\frac{1}{2}\beta^2(X_s)^2dW_s \\ 
X_t=y
\end{cases}
I should estimate the probability $\mathbb{P}\{\exists s \in [t,T] : (s,X_s) \in A  \}$, where $A$ has this form $\{(t,x) \in [0,T] \times (0,+\infty) : 0 \leq y \leq L\}$.
Can someone help me with this estimate?

Comment: Except when y=0, the answer is 1, because you have started it in that interval.  I think the solution starting from 0 is always 0, and so it never enters the stricly positives.

Comment: Thank you, even if in the article that I'm reading they state that the probability is less than c/y^2 where c is a positive constant, how can I justify it?

Comment: I may not understand what A is.  I thought A = $\{(t,x) \in [0,T] \times (0,+\infty) \} $  and the condition $ 0 \leq y \leq L$  didn't really belong in the braces, so that the probability you are looking for is the probability that the diffusion becomes positive before time T.